# Netty server can't send to Html5 websocket client

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm using Netty 4.0.31 and i create a sever chat with multi  html5 websocket client and i push message from other pakage. 
In first serveral times, client connected but it can't received message from server.
After that. client connect but **onopen event** of socket not handled, i don't know why!.

**update:** 
 **onopen event** of socket is handled. But  when i use ServerUtils.SendMessage(mesage), ServerHandler.ctxs( list client connected) is zero.

Here is my code:
Netty Server:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Start {

    static int PORT =8888;
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Start.class);

    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ServerInitializer());

            Channel ch = b.bind(PORT).sync().channel();
            logger.debug("Web socket server started at port " + PORT + '.');
            logger.debug("Open your browser and navigate to http://localhost:" + PORT + '/');

            ch.closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    void shutdownWorkers(EventLoopGroup boss,EventLoopGroup worker) {
    Future fb = boss.shutdownGracefully();
    Future fw = worker.shutdownGracefully();
    try {
        fb.await();
        fw.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
}
```

class ServerHandler:

```
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.TextWebSocketFrame;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<TextWebSocketFrame> {

    public static List<ChannelHandlerContext> ctxs = Collections
            .synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ChannelHandlerContext>());

  final  Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerHandler.class);
    public static Map<String, String> mapMute = new HashMap<String, String>();



    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext chc,
            TextWebSocketFrame txtMsg) throws Exception {

        String messReceived = txtMsg.text();

    }

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Channel incoming=ctx.channel();
        incoming.writeAndFlush("hello");
      //   ctxs.add(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
     //  ctxs.remove(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public  void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctxs.remove(ctx);
        super.channelInactive(ctx); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        logger.debug("remove "+ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public  void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctxs.add(ctx);
        super.channelActive(ctx); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        logger.debug("add " + ctx);
    }

}
```

class ServerInitialized:

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerProtocolHandler;


public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("codec-http", new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/websocket"));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerHandler());


    }

}
```

Class ServerUtils ( method send to client from other package)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.mpcc.springmvc.fb.model.MessPoJo;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.TextWebSocketFrame;
import io.netty.util.AttributeKey;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ServerUtils {

    public static void sendMessages(Object objEvent) {

        System.out.println(ServerHandler.ctxs);

        if (Collections.synchronizedList(ServerHandler.ctxs) != null && !Collections.synchronizedList(ServerHandler.ctxs).isEmpty()) {
            for (ChannelHandlerContext ctx : ServerHandler.ctxs) {
                AttributeKey<String> aKey = AttributeKey.valueOf(objEvent.toString());
                if (null == ctx.channel().attr(aKey).get()) {
                    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(
                            String.valueOf(objEvent)));
                    ctx.channel().attr(aKey).setIfAbsent(objEvent.toString());
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error in ctxs");
        }
    }
}
```

And websocket Client Html5:

```
<html><head><title>Web Socket Test</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket;
if (!window.WebSocket) {
  window.WebSocket = window.MozWebSocket;
}
if (window.WebSocket) {
  socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket");
  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    debugger;
    var ta = document.getElementById('responseText');
    ta.value = ta.value + '\n server: ' + event.data
  };
  socket.onopen = function(event) {
    var ta = document.getElementById('responseText');
    ta.value = "Web Socket opened!";
  };
  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    var ta = document.getElementById('responseText');
    ta.value = ta.value + "Web Socket closed"; 
  };
} else {
  alert("Your browser does not support Web Socket.");
}

function send(message) {
  if (!window.WebSocket) { return; }
  if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
    socket.send(message);
  } else {
    alert("The socket is not open.");
  }
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" name="message" value="Hello, World!"/><input type="button" value="Send Web Socket Data"
       onclick="send(this.form.message.value)" />
<h3>Output</h3>
<textarea id="responseText" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's possible that the connection is opening very quickly because you're connected via `localhost`.  This means `socket.readyState` may go from `CONNECTING` to `OPEN` before the `onopen` handler is set.  Try inserting `console.log(socket.readyState);` just before `socket.onopen = ...` and match the result to [one of these constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants)

Comment: i  tried but readyState alway 0. 
Method ChanelActive is handled nothing on websocket. @MTCoster